# Dreamweaver highlight jquery as regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery, dreamweaver

why Dreaweaver highlight as RegExp what's wrong with my code?

```
$(this).attr({'width':this.width /2, 'height':this.height/ 2});
```

its highlight from `/2` to `/2`.

thank you

I used this code for `<img/>` tag I think its better use `attr()` instead of `css()`

Comment: I'm not sure you can pass `attr()` an array of attribute names, only one name at a time.

Comment: This might help..http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt1.html

Comment: No it's not "better" in any way. HTML attributes **are** deprecated for styling. HTML is for structure. CSS for style. Using `width` and `height` attributes was something from the 90's. But if you insist, your application should work with `attr` still. Browsers are supposed to have backwards compatibility..

Comment: @FabrícioMatté but in IE it dosent work img tag without width and height attributes. ok thank you I got it!

Comment: @Sam I've seen some glitches where it wouldn't get the computed width/height before the image loads, but it should work fine as long as you define the width and height in the CSS as well. You can even do it in the html: `<img style="width:100px; height:100px;" />` (I tested it in IE6-9) `=]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why Dreaweaver highlight as RegExp?

The regex highlighting has nothing to do with your code. It's a major highlighting problem which has been present in DreamWeaver for as long as I've used it (DW CS5 - CS6).

> What's wrong with my code?

Object properties shouldn't be quoted and I'm not sure if `this.width` and `this.height` return what you're expecting. Also you shouldn't use attributes for that, use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) when you want to apply styling. HTML Attributes are deprecated for that.

```
$(this).css({width: $(this).width()/2, height: $(this).height()/2});
```

Comment: thank you for quick answer I used attr() if not IE make problem with showing img without width and height attributes.

Comment: @Sam Mhm I see, I've experienced some bugs with that. If you set the initial width and height in the CSS however, it should work fine. `=]`

Comment: @Sam In fact, I develop addons for phpbb2 which uses a template from the 90's, and even though it does annoy me slightly to see the width and height html attributes, I wouldn't change them as long as the application works fine, hence I understand why you'd keep it as it is. I just pointed that out so you can use *best practices* when starting a fresh new project.